# How to connect two google sheet workbooks using SUMIFS?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have the following formula

```
SUMIFS(Sheet1!I2:I12,Sheet1!H2:H12,"1111-1111",Sheet1!B2:B12,"1111")
```

I want the Sheet1 from a separate workbook (not sheets in the same workbook), how can I do this?

My workbook1 is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L4t2xkmHPAOn8uGT3bFy56UMWrZaHsyq4FlOh6uR2g0/edit?usp=sharing

I want to do following in workbook2

```
= SUMIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VayuaMlSMvkhBKKuQnRTuTwk6kshFWQanWxa5KWh2ag","Sheet1!I2:I12"),IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VayuaMlSMvkhBKKuQnRTuTwk6kshFWQanWxa5KWh2ag", "Sheet1!H2:H12"),"1111-1111",IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VayuaMlSMvkhBKKuQnRTuTwk6kshFWQanWxa5KWh2ag", "Sheet1!B2:B12"),"1111")
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheets with example of desired result

Comment: Hi, I have added my workbook1 and the sumiff I am trying to use in workbook2 but does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1L4t2xkmHPAOn8uGT3bFy56UMWrZaHsyq4FlOh6uR2g0", "Sheet1!A:I"), 
 "select sum(Col9) 
  where Col8 = '1111-1111' 
    and Col2 = 1111 
  label sum(Col9)''")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this works, can you help explain the query? why does 1111-1111 is in quotes and and 1111is not and what is label?

Comment: sure, its due to formatting. query diferentiates between numeric numbers and text strings/plain text. 1111 is number - you can test this with =ISNUMBER(B2) - so you don't need to wrap it into single quotes while text strings like 1111-1111 needs to be always wrapped in singlequotes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `IMPORTRANGE` to bring in the columns you want to your active sheet. You can either import the data first and then use a formula in another cell to work with it, or you can use `IMPORTRANGE` inside your `SUMIF` formula.

EDIT: [Here's a workbook that has it working.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fNnPKg81tIW5PlMFFnRH-dE48yZLyoIgiArucE5PZn4/edit?usp=sharing)

The formula in `Sheet1!A1` is `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L4t2xkmHPAOn8uGT3bFy56UMWrZaHsyq4FlOh6uR2g0/edit?usp=sharing","Sheet1!A1:I12")`, which pulls the data from your shared workbook1 into this sheet.

The formula in `Sheet2!A2` is `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!I2:I12,Sheet1!H2:H12,"1111-1111",Sheet1!B2:B12,"1111")`

You could also put the `SUMIFS` formula on `Sheet1` if you prefer. It's 2 steps instead of one, but it works!

Comment: Above gives me an error saying argument must be a range

Comment: My example only has "dummy" links that don't actually reference a sheet. 

I updated my answer with an example of how to use the `IMPORTRANGE` function with your actual sheets so they reference a real range. 

I'd recommend trying a single `IMPORTRANGE` in an empty cell and once you've seen it work, return to the formula in my example and try putting all 3 in.

Comment: Yes, I used my links in the example, the sum works with one importrange, but sumifs does not work with 3 importranges, I am unable to figure out why, it says argument must be a range = SUMIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VayuaMlSMvkhBKKuQnRTuTwk6kshFWQanWxa5KWh2ag", "Sheet1!I2:I12"),IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VayuaMlSMvkhBKKuQnRTuTwk6kshFWQanWxa5KWh2ag", "Sheet1!H2:H12"),"1111-1111",IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VayuaMlSMvkhBKKuQnRTuTwk6kshFWQanWxa5KWh2ag", "Sheet1!B2:B12"),"1111")

Comment: I think I made a mistake in my formula - I left out a couple apostrophes in the range. Try using your links but add `"'Sheet1'!I2:I12"` (I had originally written it as `"Sheet1!I2:I12"` without apostrophes before and after `Sheet1`.
Also, how many separate sheets are you importing information from? It may be easiest to just create a separate tab, use a single `IMPORTRANGE` to bring all necessary data into the sheet you're using, and then use your original formula to reference it there.

Comment: it does not work,gives the same error, does the importrange return a range? or something else? how can I make it a range?

Comment: Here are two sheets that may help. [Workbook 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzUYjkQsdgf4SID2jDDtVSxfcCJR3Teyb0XvSdDRjuE/edit?usp=sharing), [Workbook 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kNKpA0buJdAYJDLOwZs7uA_I_wHxlVpjQby8CwqdEZM/edit?usp=sharing). "Workbook 1" has an `IMPORTRANGE` function that pulls data from "Workbook 2". The `IMPORTRANGE` will import as big a range as you want (up to the entire other sheet). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, my importrange works, sum works with importrange, sumif does not work with importrange,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219611/discussion-between-confuseddesk-and-umesha-gunasinghe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IMPORTRANGE` formula to pull data from another sheet.
You can either embed the `IMPORTRANGE` in your formula in order to pull directly from it, or you can use the formula on its own in a new sheet, and pull from the sheet located within the same Spreadsheet for ease of access and a shorter formula overall.
Updating the spreadsheet you are pulling from will automatically update the data coming from the `IMPORTRANGE` formula.

For example:

[image: example]

A1 contains the basic formula `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I8BiB-2gSFueLIKiGsMY-URLOpnB8QzbUrx8/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!I1:I12")`

while B1 contains `=sum(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I8BiB-2gSFueLIKiGsMY-URLOpnB8QzbUrx8/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!I1:I12"))`

Make sure you replace the URLs above with the one for the sheet you are trying to pull from